# How to add add a 3rd indexable attribute to DynamoDb through the CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I am trying to follow a tutorial which explains proper usage of DynamoDB through something called  index overloading. The tutorial is [here](https://www.trek10.com/blog/dynamodb-single-table-relational-modeling). I am creating the DynamoDB through the CDK.

The problem:
The tutorial mentions that the indexes will include: the partition key, the sort key, and a 3rd field called "data" which will serve in itself as a sort key:

> Create a DynamoDB table with three generic attributes: “partition key”, “sort key”, and **“data”**
>
> The three generic attributes will be used to support two indexes: the main table index which uses pk as the partition and sk as the sort key, and a global secondary index which uses sk as the partition and **data as the sort**.

As you can see above, this logic involves the presence of 3 attributes. But the AWS CDK  allows the addition of partition key and sort key - no other attributes can be included in the initial schema description. How do I create an index as described above, which includes the "data" attribute, when there is no "data" attribute?

Answer (score 1):

When creating your DynamoDB table with CDK, you have a few [methods at your disposal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.Table.html#methods) that help you define secondary indexes.

For example, here's a snippet of CDK (javascript) that creates a DynamoDB table and adds a secondary index:

```
    const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, "Table", {
      billingMode: dynamodb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST, // Use on-demand billing mode
      sortKey: {name: "SK", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING},
      partitionKey: {name: "PK", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING}
    });

    table.addGlobalSecondaryIndex({
      indexName: "GSI1",
      partitionKey: {name: "GSI1PK", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING},
      sortKey: {name: "GSI1SK", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was twofold:

1. I must RTFM - the CDK documentation clearly specifies that you can use *either* L2 constructs which are higher level APIs, *or* the L1 CFN constructs.
2. No code. Had I posted some code, viewers would have seen that I used the L2 construct `Table` of the CDK, when I should have used the lower level L1 `CfnTable` which allows for greater customisation, and does expose the possibility to define your own `keySchema` and `attributeDefinitions` as per the specified need in the `CfnTableProps`.